# why input tag and button tag are not coming together and coming in separate line

Tags: html, css

[image: as shown]

This my code in HTML and CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>assignment1</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <meta name = "description" content="assignment">
 <meta name = "keywords" content="php, assignment">
 <meta name = "author"   content="Kamal">
 <meta name = "viewport"   content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "css/assignment1.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container"> 
     <div class="row">
        <div class = "col-xs-12 col-xm-6">
           <img class ="img1" src="images/logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class = "col-xs-12 col-xm-6">
           <u class ="new"><p class ="new1"> Login to My Account</p></u>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class = "col-xs-12 col-xm-12" >
           <form class = "k1">
           <input class = "new2" type="text" id="namef" placeholder="Search entire story here...." name="Search">
           <button type = "submit" class = "new3"><img src="images/search.png"></button>
           </form>
        </div>
      </div>  
     <div class="row">
       <div class = "col-xs-12 col-xm-12">
         <hr class = "new4">
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
body{background-color: #d7e7f4}
div.container{width:954px; background-color: #FFFFFF}
img.img1{margin-top: 25px; margin-left: 22px}
u.new{color:#007BAF}
p.new1{color:#007BAF; margin-top:-50px; margin-right:22px; margin-left:790px; font-size:14px}
form.k1{margin-top:-15px; margin-left:705px; margin-right:22px}
input.new2{ padding: 2px; font-size: 13px; border: 1px solid #007BAF; width: 64%;}
button.new3{border: none; background-color:#FFFFFF }
hr.new4{margin-top:100px; margin-bottom:1000px; border-top:4px solid black; border-radius:50px; width:954px}
```

This is problem description: the webpage which I am designing is not the same looking as I am supposed to make(Shown in the image attached). Main issue is with the input tag and search box not coming properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="row">
        <div class = "col-xs-12 col-xm-12" >
           <form>
           <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-auto">
           <input class = "new2" type="text" id="namef" placeholder="Search entire story here...." name="Search">
                </div>

                <div class="col-auto">   
                    <button type = "submit" class = "new3"><img src="images/search.png"/>
                </div>
               </div> 
           </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please add explanation of your changes and why.

Comment: form-row class is a variant of a grid that overrides the default.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#auto-sizing

Answer (score 0):

Your full webpage is here. Copy enter code and try

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="fluid-container">
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-xs-12 col-md-6 logo">
                LOGO
            </div>
            <div class = "col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="float-right">
                <a href="#" class ="login">Login to My Account</a>
                <form class = "k1">
                    <input class = "search-box" type="text" id="namef" placeholder="Search entire story here...." name="Search">
                    <button type = "submit" class = "search-btn">SEARCH</button>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                <hr class = "new4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.fluid-container{
    background:#d7e7f4;
    height:100vh;
}
.container{
    background:#FFF;
    height:100vh;
}
.logo{
        padding: 15px;
}
.login{
    color: #007BAF;
    text-decoration: underline;
    display: block;
    padding: 12px 0;
}
.search-box{
      font-size: 16px;
    min-width: 200px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.search-btn{
        background: #007BAF;
    border: 0;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

OUTPUT SCREENSHOT

[image]

Comment: Please add explanation of your changes and why.